# Blender model adds extra materials when imported to Unity

Tags: materials, unity

My model is made up of a few other models I made before, I combined them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, in Blender it tells me I have 1 Material, but once I import it into Unity It gives me extra Materials from those models I joined together.

How do I keep it as 1 Material when I import it into Unity?

Comment: Please give an example picture

Answer (score 0):

Without files hard to say for sure, but my guess would be that this is because of blender's way of storing a set of polygon texture references separate from materials and in some cases also exporting that. This happens usually when you select texture in *uv view* while having faces selected; blender links the texture to only selected faces.

There's (at least) two ways to fix this:

- Blender way: select your object, while in edit mode hit A to select everything, go to *uv view* and select everything there as well. Then at bottom of the view select texture. (this way every face has the same texture and as result there should be only one material named after texture you selected)
- Unity way: I prefer this way and am pretty sure this would be the better for your situation as well: in unity, open model *import settings*, find second last item *Material Naming* and set it to *From Model's Material*. This way should make sure no other than explicitly created materials are imported.

Comment: I've tried the Unity way and it's still Screwed up. I'll take a look at the Blender way and see if that helps.

Comment: What is "polygon texture references"? From your description looks like you mean way of assigning textures which works based on face textures, only ones selected get the texture. Note that this works that way only in Blender Internal. Also there isn't UV view, most likely you mean UV Image editor window.